# Is this assertion about g.c.d. true?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Is it true that if $\gcd(a,bc)=1$ and $\gcd(b,c)=1$ then $\gcd(a,b^2)=\gcd(a,c^2)=\gcd(ab^2,c^2)=\gcd(a,(bc)^2)=1$?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the two conditions imply that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all pairwise relatively prime.